# Converting Varchar to Decimal Error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I uploaded a csv file into SQL Server and columns that were supposed to be `Int` or `Decimal` were simply `varchar` and I'm trying to convert `16.50` to `0.165` or `6.40` to `0.064`. I've created a new table and tried to convert the data doing this:

```
alter table bplateinfo2018
  add [New O Swing Percentage] as decimal(5,4) 

  update bplateinfo2018
  Set [New O Swing Percentage] = [Original O Swing Percentage] / 100
```

I get the error

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 16.50 to data type int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert that before the division, or use `100.0`. It's trying to convert to `INTEGER` because 100 is an integer.

```
select '16.50' / 100.0
select try_convert(decimal(4,2),'16.50') / 100
```

If you know all of your `varchar` values can be implictly converted to decimal, then simply:

```
update bplateinfo2018
  Set [New O Swing Percentage] = [Original O Swing Percentage] / 100.0
```

Otherwise, you will need [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or something similar.

```
update bplateinfo2018
  Set [New O Swing Percentage] = [Original O Swing Percentage] / 100.0
  where try_convert(decimal(16,4),[Original O Swing Percentage]) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a `varchar` value representing a decimal directly to an `int` (`int` is not a `decimal`). This seems to be the misunderstanding you have here, based on your title *"Converting Varchar to Decimal Error in SQL"*, despite the error being *"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 16.50 to data type **int**."*.

As an example, the statement below will fail:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, '16.50');
```

Instead, you need to convert to a decimal first, and then an `int`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int,CONVERT(decimal(4,2),'16.50'));
```

Comment: It's an exact duplicate

Comment: So it is @Sami. I'll close this topic.